# How can I reduce the number of SQL queries I need for this to work?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, where-clause

So.. I know a little bit of programming but my skills are limited. Today I'm trying to make a simple query to get the health personal working at the hospital I currently work in between the dates I choose.

I want to have 4 input dates like

[image: this]

Its in spanish so here is the traduction:

The date inputs are "filters"

```
Started working >= to this date
Started working <= to this date
Quit the job >= to this date
Quit the job <= to this date
```

And the 2 selects inputs are the title and specialization degree that personal have. (I need the option that both can be null)

So I can work around this making an SQL query for every possible case like this:

```
    if ($titulo == '0' && $especialidad == '0' && $date1!=null && $date2==null && 
$bdesde==null && $bhasta==null){     

$sql_query= "select * from personal where starting_date >= '$date1'" }
    
elseif ( ... and so on
```

The database is MySQL.

But I was wondering if there is a way to do what I want with less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use case expressions and conditional logic:

```
select * 
from personal 
where 
    (:starting_date_after      is null or starting_date >= :starting_date_after)
    and (:starting_date_before is null or starting_date <= :starting_date_before)
    and (:ending_date_after    is null or ending_date   >= :ending_date_after)
    and (:ending_date_before   is null or ending_date   <= :ending_date_before)
```

This assumes that your query accepts 4 parameters, which may be `null` (ie not provided by the user) or set (ie given by the user): parameters `:starting_date_after` and `:starting_date_before` are meant to filter table column `starting_date`, while `:ending_date_after` and `:ending_date_before` apply to `ending_date`.

Note that you should be using parameterized queries (as shown above) rather than concatenating variables in the query string, to make your code more efficient, and, more importantly, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I tried that but it isn't working. I don't know if im wrong but in this case if starting_date_after is null then the query would bring all the values from personal.
The only solution that I proved and it works is to get all the possible combinations using IFs statments. But its 4! posibilities (24) without counting the other 2 filters ( title and specialization degree)

Comment: @nap_-: *if starting_date_after is null then the query would bring all the values from personal.*: no, it depends on the other parameters too. Only if all 4 parameters are `null`, will the query returns all the rows (which seems logical).

Comment: Yes, my bad there. The problem was that starting_date_after wasn't null but an empty strig. I don't know if is the best solution but i did this inside the where
´´(starting_date_after  = ' ' or starting_date >=  starting_date_after) ´´

Comment: @nap_-: you can handle empty strings to, like `(:starting_date_after is null or :starting_date_after = '' or starting_date >= :starting_date_after)`, and so on.

Comment: Yeah. I just did that. Thanks for the answers. I'm still a noob programming T_T